# Email Send Failure

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

If I've list of emailTo address and one of them is invalid.

Does `client.Send(email);` returns failure/Exception?

Comment: Did you even try and look online, MSDN... SmtpClient.SendMail(MailMessage message)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx

Comment: My apologies, we had a production issue and througt I would get expert advice here. Agree, Ishould have first looked at MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the SMTPClient's Send(MailMessage) method raises a [SmtpFailedRecipientsException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception.aspx) exception if one or more recipient addresses were incorrect or unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. For server local addresses (if you send from abc@domain.com to def@domain.com) mail server may return error immediately, but generally speaking mail server processes requests asynchronously and does not return any error if recipient address is invalid.

Comment: That is incorrect, there is a specific Asnyc method to call. SmtpClient.SendAsync!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx

Comment: Not true. Server processes requests asynchronously, regardless how they are sent. Imagine you're sending from alice@gmail.com to bob@hotmail.com. GMail will accept your request without any error diagnostics even if bob@hotmail.com mailbox does not exist. But later you'll get an email saying your message cannot be delivered. You may get SmtpFailedRecipientException, but only if you're sending within the same domain and only if mail server is set up to reject immediately.

Comment: From MSDN SmtpFailedRecipientException "Represents the exception that is thrown when the SmtpClient is not able to complete a Send or SendAsync operation to a particular recipient." this is not dependant on it being the same domain, thats rediculous, its dependant on the Mail server response and what the response code is.  http://email.about.com/cs/standards/a/smtp_error_code_2.htm

Comment: Just try to send to non-existing mailbox between domains and within domain and you'll get the results I'm talking about. This is real world experience, not MSDN. Absence of SmtpFailedRecipientException is not indicator of recipient mail address existence.

Comment: You were the only person talking about "mail address existence", it has nothing to do with the SmtpClient, Asncronous Message Handling, or even .Net which is what the question is Tagged as. If the questions was how can I tell if a Email address is valid with .Net SmtpClient then maybe your answer would be somewhat relevant, but even then I doubt it.

Comment: Questions was "Does client.Send(email); returns failure/Exception?". Correct answers is SOMETIMES, but not always.

Answer (score -1):

This is all in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) of the SmtpClient class, which you should always read before asking:

> When sending e-mail using Send to multiple recipients and the SMTP server accepts some recipients as valid and rejects others, Send sends e-mail to the accepted recipients and then a SmtpFailedRecipientsException is thrown. The exception will contain a listing of the recipients that were rejected.